# How Can I Incorporate gdx-bullet into my game engine?

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I use gdx-bullet without using libgdx? Meaning how do I use the gdx-bullet extensions standalone without using the full libgdx library? Using libgdx is fine for the math.

When I try to run the file, this error message appears:

`com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx64.so' for target: Linux, 64-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:118)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
    at tester.ExampleGame.initGame(ExampleGame.java:94)
    at display.Display.loop(Display.java:218)
    at display.Display.run(Display.java:116)
    at display.Display.<init>(Display.java:95)
    at tester.ExampleGame.<init>(ExampleGame.java:56)
    at tester.ExampleGame.main(ExampleGame.java:60)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: libgdx64.so
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:126)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:261)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:115)
    ... 7 more`

Comment: Should work fine. What's the problem you're having? Which platform are your targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do but you can use Bullet without loading all the Android app specific things. I use a standalone Java game server that runs Bullet.

Use:

```
GdxNativesLoader.load();
```

Then you should be able to get gdx-bullet working.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with not loading "Android app specific things". Libgdx never forces you to use any of it. If you want to use parts of it that use native libraries then you will ofcourse need to load those native libraries. If you are targeting android, then those native libraries will certainly be "Android specific things". Likewise, if you are targeting ios, then those libraries will be "ios specific things".

Comment: I did, but it throws an error as seen in the edit above.